# Creating a Dataframe with a schema in the Spark workers side, in a Spark Streaming app

Tags: pandas, dataframe, spark-streaming

I have developed a spark streaming app where I have data stream of json strings.

```
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "appname")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
sqlContext = sql.SQLContext(sc)

#batch width in time
stream = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
stream.checkpoint("checkpoint")

# mqtt setup
brokerUrl = "tcp://localhost:1883"
topic = "test"

# mqtt stream
DS = MQTTUtils.createStream(stream, brokerUrl, topic)

# transform DStream to be able to read json as a dict
jsonDS = kvs.map(lambda v: json.loads(v))

#create SQL-like rows from the json 
sqlDS = jsonDS.map(lambda x: Row(a=x["a"], b=x["b"], c=x["c"], d=x["d"]))

#in each batch do something
sqlDS.foreachRDD(doSomething)

# run
stream.start()
stream.awaitTermination()

def doSomething(time,rdd):

   data = rdd.toDF().toPandas()
```

This code above is working as expected: I receive some jsons in a stringified manner and I can convert each batch to a dataframe, also converting it to a Pandas DataFrame.

So far so good.

The problem comes if I want to add a different schema to the DataFrame.
The method `toDF()` assumes a `schema=None` in the following function: `sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)`.

If I try to access `sqlContext` from inside `doSomething()`, obviosuly it is not defined. If I try to make it available there with a global variable I get the typical error that it cannot be serialized.

I have also read the sqlContext can only be used in the Spark Driver and not in the workers.

So the question is: how is the `toDF()` working in the first place, as it needs the sqlContext? And how can I add a schema to it (hopefully without changing the source)?

Creating the DataFrame in the driver doesnt seem to be an option because I cannot serialize it to the workers.

Maybe I am not seeing this properly.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

define the following:

```
def getSparkSessionInstance(sparkConf):
if ("sparkSessionSingletonInstance" not in globals()):
    globals()["sparkSessionSingletonInstance"] = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config(conf=sparkConf) \
        .getOrCreate()
return globals()["sparkSessionSingletonInstance"]
```

and then from the worker just call:

```
spark = getSparkSessionInstance(rdd.context.getConf())
```

taken from [DataFrame and SQL Operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations)